# update dataframe based on union function spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hello guys i have a dataframe that needs to be updated based on another dataframe there are field that we are going to sum and other to just take the new value provided by the second dataframe  , here what i did

```
  val hist1 = spark.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true") //reading the headers
      .load("C:/Users/MHT/Desktop/histocaisse_dte1.csv")
      .withColumn("article_id", 'article_id.cast(LongType))
      .withColumn("pos_id", 'pos_id.cast(LongType))
      .withColumn("qte", 'qte.cast(LongType))
      .withColumn("ca", 'ca.cast(DoubleType))

    hist1.show

    val hist2 = spark.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true") //reading the headers
      .load("C:/Users/MHT/Desktop/his2.csv")
      .withColumn("article_id", 'article_id.cast(LongType))
      .withColumn("date", 'date.cast(DateType))
      .withColumn("qte", 'qte.cast(LongType))
      .withColumn("ca", 'ca.cast(DoubleType))

    hist2.show

    val df3 = hist1.unionAll(hist2)
    //      
    val df4 = df3.groupBy("pos_id", "article_id").agg($"pos_id", $"article_id", max("date"), sum("qte"), sum("ca"))
    df4.show

+------+----------+----------+---+----+----------+
|pos_id|article_id|      date|qte|  ca|sale_price|
+------+----------+----------+---+----+----------+
|     1|         1|2000-01-07|  3| 3.5|      14.3|
|     2|         2|2000-01-07| 15|12.0|      13.2|
|     3|         2|2000-01-07|  4| 1.2|      14.3|
|     4|         2|2000-01-07|  4| 1.2|      12.3|
+------+----------+----------+---+----+----------+

+------+----------+----------+---+----+----------+
|pos_id|article_id|      date|qte|  ca|sale_price|
+------+----------+----------+---+----+----------+
|     1|         1|2000-01-08|  3| 3.5|      14.5|
|     2|         2|2000-01-08| 15|12.0|      20.2|
|     3|         2|2000-01-08|  4| 1.2|      17.5|
|     4|         2|2000-01-08|  4| 1.2|      18.2|
|     5|         3|2000-01-08| 15| 1.2|      11.2|
|     6|         1|2000-01-08|  2|1.25|      13.5|
|     6|         2|2000-01-08|  2|1.25|      14.3|
+------+----------+----------+---+----+----------+



    +------+----------+----------+--------+-------+
|pos_id|article_id| max(date)|sum(qte)|sum(ca)|
+------+----------+----------+--------+-------+
|     2|         2|2000-01-08|      30|   24.0|
|     3|         2|2000-01-08|       8|    2.4|
|     1|         1|2000-01-08|       6|    7.0|
|     5|         3|2000-01-08|      15|    1.2|
|     6|         1|2000-01-08|       2|   1.25|
|     6|         2|2000-01-08|       2|   1.25|
|     4|         2|2000-01-08|       8|    2.4|
+------+----------+----------+--------+-------+
```

How would the request be , if i want to append the field sale_price and consider the new sale_price provided by the second dataframe
 how would this request be

```
 val df4 = df3.groupBy("pos_id", "article_id").agg($"pos_id", $"article_id", max("date"), sum("qte"), sum("ca"))
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` on the last line as the following

```
val df4 = df3.groupBy("pos_id", "article_id").agg(max("date"), sum("qte"), sum("ca")).join(hist2.select("pos_id", "article_id", "sale_price"), Seq("pos_id", "article_id"))
```

You should have your desired output